# How to find multiple minimal/canonical covers or rearrange them to find new ones

Tags: database, database-design, closures, functional-dependencies, canonicalization

I have a relation and function dependencies as follows:

```
R = (A, B, C, D, E)
F = (A -> B C,
   B C -> D,
   A C -> D E)
```

Now I am going to compute the minimal/canonical cover using [this video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiEAfRoHIH8)

---

So firstly I check if I have singleton right-hand sides in my FDs. No I don't, so I have to split them up. I.e. `A -> B C` is split into `A -> B` and `A -> C`. Similarly for `A C -> D E`.

So now I have...

```
F = (A -> B,
     A -> C,
   B C -> D,
   A C -> D,
   A C -> E)
```

---

Secondly, I check if any FDs have more than 1 LHS attributes. If they do, I see if any one of them can be eliminated by checking if their closure contains the other element. If it does, then we don't need that other element.

So for `B C -> D`, `B closure` is `B` and `C closure` is `C`. None of the closures contain the other attribute so we cannot eliminate `B C -> D`.

So now we move to `A C -> D`. `A closure` is `ABCDE`, we can instantly see that `A`'s closure contains `C`. So `C` is and *extraneous attribute*  and can be removed so our new set of FDs is...

```
F = (A -> B,
     A -> C,
   B C -> D,
     A -> D,
   A C -> E)
```

So now we move to the last one: `A C -> E`, again, `A`'s closure is `ABCDE`, which contains `C` so we can eliminate the `C` from the FD. So our set of FDs is now:

```
F = (A -> B,
     A -> C,
   B C -> D,
     A -> D,
     A -> E)
```

---

Lastly, we check if there are any redundant FDs. We do this by going through each FD, covering it up, and seeing if the closure of its LHS contains its RHS.

So for `A -> B`, we cover it up and compute `A closure`, which is `ACDE` which doesnt contain `B` so we cannot eliminate `A -> B`. We do this for all FDs and we end up seeing that we can only eliminate `A -> D` because when we cover `A -> D` up and compute `A closure` it contains `D`, so we don't need `A -> D`

---

So now our new set of FDs are:

```
F = (A -> B,
     A -> C,
   B C -> D,
     A -> E)
```

### Now my question is:

Is my final set of FDs the correct minimal/canonical cover? Can it be written in another way? Also, In the video, it says that multiple canonical covers can exist for a given set of functional dependencies. How can I discover these?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For eg.

```
X→YZ
Y→XZ
Z→XY
```

check out this answer with more than one possibility of minimal set

**1:**

```
X→Y,
Y→Z,
Z→X
```

**2:**

```
Z→Y,
Y→X,
X→Z
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked all your steps and your final set is correct.

That said, I'm not sure about the multiple covers thing. The only difference between minimal cover and canonical cover is that a canonical cover is "allowed" to have more than one attribute on the right hand side, whereas minimal cover is not [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356707/difference-between-canonical-cover-and-minimal-cover). In this (trivial) sense you could obviously write the same set FDs in a different way.

On the other hand, I don't know if there could be two different sets of *minimal* covers with the same closure. I would say it is impossible, but that's just my intuition and I don't have elements to back it up.

Comment: If I don't need to have singleton RHS for canonical covers, can I just say that my new canonical cover is `A -> BCDE`? Because `A->BCE` and `BC->D` So I can add the D in as well?

Comment: No! The minimal cover is `A->BCE` **and** `BC->D`. If you only write `A->BCDE` you're losing a part of information, namely that `BC` determines `D`. On the other hand, writing `A->BCDE` *and* `BC->D` would preserve every original FD, but it would not be a minimal cover since, as you already determined before, `A->D` is redundant.